# How to ignore or redirect a http request in Django?

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I use an Angular 4 frontend and Python Django in the backend.
If I click on the detail button I run the `openDetail` method in my component

```
openDetail(id:number){
    this.router.navigate(['/motor/detail', {"id": id}])
  }
```

the browser opens the detail component with the URL `http://localhost:8000/motor/detail;id=21`. Perfect. Important to know is, that I just need the id to work with them in my detail component.

But if I refresh the page I run into a 404 error. --> `The current path, motor/detail;id=21, didn't match any of these.` Well, this is also clear and jumped into the backend.

**main - urls.py**

```
#... some other urls...
url(r'^motor/', include('motorControll.urls')),
```

**motors - urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
url(r'^overview/$', views.MotorMapping.as_view({'get': 'getAllData'})),
url(r'^detail/$', views.index, name="index"),
url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.MotorMapping.as_view({'get': 'getById'})),
url(r'^detail/save/$', views.MotorMapping.as_view({'post': 'save'})),
```

How can I ignore this call or run a redirect to the index page?
I need the id, because the next step, after load the detail page is to load the details by this url `http://localhost:8000/motor/detail/21` , it returns JSON with all data.

Comment: Why is there `;` in your URL. Is it a typo?

Comment: actually not. it is from a Angular Tutorial https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero  i hope I understand the content correct :) --> scroll a little bit down, it's in the blue box `Matrix URL notation`

Comment: I would suggest that you use query params instead of matrix URL notation. It is really standard for rest also it will be easy for you to use other than in angular

Answer (score 0):

Your URL mapping in motors.urls is configured properly for the URL `/motor/detail/21` -- so it works. But it's not configured for a URL like `/motor/detail;id=21`.

If you added another route to motors.url so that `/motor/detail;id=21` works -- something like `url(r'^detail;id=(?P<id>\d+)$', views.MotorMapping.as_view({'get': 'getById'})),` then the URL would return raw JSON, so that's NOT what you want.

Instead, the actual solution is more complicated -- you want the URL to be routed to your single page app, and not Django, and have Angular take care of loading the data from Django Rest Framework.